# Regular Expression to limit all letters less than 100 characters

Tags: regex

I need the regular expression that would limit the number of characters to 100 and allow the use of 0-9, !@.,;:'"?-    and all lower and upper case letters

Comment: Is zero characters allowed? Or does it have to be 1-100?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z!@.,;:'"?-]{1,100}\z/
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. Inside character classes most metacharacters (including dots) lose their meaning.

Comment: Learning something new every day! Would have escaped it - probably broken the regex. Good that I chose not to answer...

Comment: That allows for 101 characters if the last character is a newline. Newlines aren't even suppose to be allowed. Use `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: You could also replace the "A-Za-z" with "\p{L}", if you're interested in more than ASCII, and the regex supports Unicode.

Answer (score 12):

```
^(.{1,100})$
```

`.`  This will allow all the characters numbers and special characters also
`{1,100}` this the range you need to specific like min and max count

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the language, but should be

```
^[0-9A-Za-z!@\.;:'"?-]{1,100}$
```

As pointed out in comments, and just to avoid usage of bad example:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z!@.,;:'"?-]{1,100}\z
```

Comment: That allows for 101 characters if the last character is a newline. Newlines aren't even suppose to be allowed. Use `\z` instead of `$`. That doesn't allow for `,` as it should. The `\ ` before the `.` is superfluous (just like it would be before `?`).

Comment: @ikegami - thanks. I'm trying to help, though I'm a bit new to this. your comments are very welcome.