# Java regular expression: A-Z and - or _, but only once

Tags: java, regex

I've only dabbled in regular expressions and was wondering if someone could help me make a Java regex, which matches a string with these qualities:

1. It is 1-14 characters long
2. It consists only of A-Z, a-z and the letters _ or -
3. The symbol - and _ must be contained only once (together) and not at the start

It should match

- Hello-Again
- ThisIsValid
- AlsoThis_

but not

- -notvalid
- Not-Allowed-This
- Nor-This_thing
- VeryVeryLongStringIndeed

I've tried the following regex string

```
[a-zA-Z^\\-_]+[\\-_]?[a-zA-Z^\\-_]*
```

and it seems to work. However, I'm not sure how to do the total character limiting part with this approach. I've also tried

```
[[a-zA-Z]+[\\-_]?[a-zA-Z]*]{1,14}
```

but it matches (for example) abc-cde_aa which it shouldn't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display any research or effort albeit stating the desired requisites.

Comment: Must've caught you all on a bad day, when questions like these are answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078259/regular-expression-to-limit-all-letters-less-than-100-characters

Comment: I have put it in the reopen queue following your edits - should be back shortly. I even have a nifty answer for you...

Comment: @bombax thank you for pointing out that question. Just voted to close it too. It's not a bad day or any animosity towards you. It's a question of interpretation of what is an acceptable question, as well as a debate over the tools to prevent bad questions to survive. As such closing this specific question is up for debate and I plaud Boris the Spider's effort to opine otherwise.

Comment: @Mena I totally agree that this question should have been closed when it was "give me code". Following the addition of a couple of examples that the OP has attempted, I think this becomes a perfectly good question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh wow. Just reloaded the page... I had not seen the examples! Voting to reopen. **Edit** must be really slow today, it's already been reopened in the meantime :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
(?![_-])(?!(?:.*[_-]){2,})[A-Za-z_-]{1,14}
```

The regex is quite complex, let my try and explain it.

- `(?![_-])` negative lookahead. From the start of the string assert that the first character is not `_` or `-`. The negative lookahead "peeks" of the current position and checks that it doesn't match `[_-]` which is a character group containing `_` and `-`.
- `(?!(?:.*[_-]){2,})` another negative lookahead, this time matching `(?:.*[_-]){2,}` which is a [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) repeated at least two times. The group is `.*[_-]`, it is any character followed by the same group as before. So we *don't* want to see some characters followed by `_` or `-` more than once.
- `[A-Za-z_-]{1,14}` is the simple bit. It just says the characters in the group `[A-Za-z_-]` between 1 and 14 times.

The second part of the pattern is the most tricky, but is a very common trick. If you want to see a character `A` repeated at some point in the pattern at least `X` times you want to see the pattern `.*A` at least `X` times because you must have

```
zzzzAzzzzAzzzzA....
```

You don't care what else is there. So what you arrive at is `(.*A){X,}`. Now, you don't need to capture the group - this just slows down the engine. So we make the group non-capturing - `(?:.*A){X,}`.

What you have is that you only want to see the pattern once, so you want *not* to find the pattern repeated two or more times. Hence it slots into a negative lookahead.

Here is a testcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String pattern = "(?![_-])(?!(?:.*[_-]){2,})[A-Za-z_-]{1,14}";
    final String[] tests = {
            "Hello-Again",
            "ThisIsValid",
            "AlsoThis_",
            "_NotThis_",
            "-notvalid",
            "Not-Allow-This",
            "Nor-This_thing",
            "VeryVeryLongStringIndeed",
    };
    for (final String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

Things to note:

1. the character `-` is special inside character groups. It must go at the start or end of a group otherwise it specifies a range
2. [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is tricky and often counter-intuitive. It will check for matches without consuming, allowing you to test multiple conditions on the same data.
3. the repetition quantifier `{}` is very useful. It has 3 states. `{X}` is repeated exactly `X` times. `{X,}` is repeated at least `X` times. And `{X, Y}` is repeated between `X` and `Y` times.

Comment: Perfect, I had the feeling you had to do something complex and indeed negative lookahead was something I've never seen before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

To check if string is in form `XXX-XXX` where `-XXX` or `_XXX` part is optional you can use

```
[a-zA-Z]+([-_][a-zA-Z]*)?
```

which is similar to what you already had

```
[[a-zA-Z]+[\\-_]?[a-zA-Z]*]
```

but you made crucial mistake and wrapped it entirely in `[...]` which makes it character class, and that is not what you wanted.

To check if matched part has only 1-14 length you can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism. Just place

```
(?=.{1,14}$)
```

at start of your regex to make sure that part from start of match till end of it (represented by `$`) contains of any 1-14 characters.

So your final regex can look like

```
String regex = "(?=.{1,14}$)[a-zA-Z]+([-_][a-zA-Z]*)?";
```

---

**Demo**

```
String [] data = {
    "Hello-Again",
    "ThisIsValid",
    "AlsoThis_",

    "-notvalid",
    "Not-Allowed-This",
    "Nor-This_thing",
    "VeryVeryLongStringIndeed",
};

for (String s : data)
    System.out.println(s + " : " + s.matches(regex));
```

Output:

```
Hello-Again : true
ThisIsValid : true
AlsoThis_ : true
-notvalid : false
Not-Allowed-This : false
Nor-This_thing : false
VeryVeryLongStringIndeed : false
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful in understanding the look-ahead mechanism more.

Comment: @bombax You can also find few nice informations in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation/3802238#3802238) of kind of similar question.